# token has wrong output format

Tags: webforms, tokens

I'm using Webform Charts. 
If I try to call Webform Chart token [node:webform-charts:my_data] on conformation page, it results false formatted output and can not be shown. I think it's because
' is automaticly replaced by '&quot';

Can I disable this replacement?

Thank you very much.